# What am I doing wrong in this estimation of the mass of the atmosphere?

Tags: atmospheric-science, ideal-gas, estimation

I'm trying to approximate the mass of the atmosphere. I'm treating it as an ideal gas and therefore its density follows:

$$\rho(z) = \rho(0)e^{(\frac{-mgz}{k_BT})}$$

Where I'm using $m=4.2122\cdot10^{-26}$ kg as a weighted average taking into account the nitrogen and oxygen portions of the atmosphere; $T=288.15$ K as the average temperature of the atmosphere. We also need the density at sea leve, $\rho(R_T)=1.225$ kgm^-3 Then, making use of spherical coordinates, where the $z$ coordinate is $r$ (upper and lower limits are $R_T + H$ and $R_T$ respectively, with $H=10^5$ m):

$$m=\int dm = \int\rho dv= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{R_T}^{R_T+H}r^2 \sin\theta e^{(\frac{-mgz}{k_BT})}drd\theta d\phi=4\pi\int_{R_T}^{R_T+H}\rho(R_T)r^2  e^{(\frac{-mgz}{k_BT})}dr=-4\pi\rho(R_T)(\frac{k_BT}{mg})^3[e^\frac{-mgr}{k_BT}((\frac{mgr}{k_BT})^2-2(\frac{mgr}{k_BT})+2)]_{R_T}^{R_T + H}$$

Which I inputted into Matlab, and then into my calculator, getting a result which is basically zero in both. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: As was brought up in the comments, if we take the relative distance from the ground so that the exponential in the lower limit results in 1 (so the lower limit is $0$ and the upper limit is $H$), the resulting value is much closer to the correct $5\cdot10^{18}$ kg result. However it's in the $10^{13}$ order, so it's rather far still.

Comment: Why do you integrate in spherical coordinates and yet not use $z=r\cos(\theta)$?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I missed that completely. I'll try it with the cosine now.

Comment: @Newbie I thought about it and that would bring some trouble. For example for a point at 45 degrees of colatitude (or latitude), the z component at 30 km altitude using r times cosine would be 4500 km. That's inside the Earth.

Comment: What you label as "z" is radial distance so it is "r" in spherical coordinates.

Comment: z is the relativ offset to RT, so somewhere you probably should replace it with z-RT (and then in the finally expression the exponentials are not zero, but reasonable)

Comment: Your final answer does not seem to give a very small value. It may be a prolem with the units. And indeed, at $r=R_T$ the exponential should be 1.

Comment: @lalala Originally I made it so the lower limit was 0 and the upper was H, which gave a result in the 10^13 kg order of magnitude. However that's 5 orders of magnitude below the correct value so it's definitely not correct either. I should have mentioned it though.

Comment: I apologize for my wrong comment earlier, stating that $z=r\cos\theta$. On earth if $z$ denotes altitude then it translates to $z=r$ in spherical coordinates.

Comment: You chose the absolutely most difficult way to do this calculation.  See the answer from niels nielsen, but use 14.7 pounds per square inch of earth's surface.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote
$$m=\int_{V}\rho dV=\int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi}\int_{r=R_{1}}^{R_{2}}\rho(0)e^{-\frac{mg}{k_{\rm B}T}z}r^{2}\sin\theta drd\theta d\phi$$
Now define $\alpha_{0}=\frac{mg}{k_{\rm B}T}$ and use $z=r$ since as brought up in the comments $z$ is the altitude measured from the ground and may be denoted by radial distance $r$ in spherical coordinates. You end up with
$$m=2\pi\rho(0)\int_{r=R_{1}}^{R_{2}}r^{2}e^{-\alpha_{0}r}\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta dr$$
The integration over $\theta$ is 2 and you're left with the integration over $r$:
$$m=4\pi\rho(0)\int_{r=R_{1}}^{R_{2}}r^{2}e^{-\alpha_{0}r} dr$$
This is a standard integral. You can use $u=-\alpha_{0}r$ such that $du=-\alpha_{0}dr$ and you have
$$m=-\frac{4\pi\rho(0)}{\alpha_{0}^{3}}\int_{u=-\alpha_{0}R_{1}}^{-\alpha_{0}R_{2}}u^{2}e^{u} du$$
As mentioned [here](https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-integrate-x-2-e-x-dx) the solution to this integral is $e^{u}(u^{2}-2u+2)$. I apologize for my earlier comment about how $z$ relates to $r$.

Comment: The $z$ in the atmospheric pressure equation is the height from the ground, which is not the same as the $z$ in spherical coordinates.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert That's what I was thinking, after all for a large theta if you used the cosine you would end near the Earth's core.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Then $z=r$. I'll modify the answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: I used that solution implicitly in my post, as far as I've checked (perhaps I've made a mistake inputting values), the closest I got to the correct value is still 5 orders of magnitude lower. Maybe the reasoning in my estimation is just not the best so the result, even if mathematically correct, is far from the correct one.

Comment: @agaminon Can you tell me what you get for $\frac{k_{\rm B}T}{mg}$? Because I know that the scale height of the temperature is about 8 km. Just make sure that the units of $k_{\rm B}$ and $T$ are in harmony.

Comment: @Newbie I get 9633 for the values I outlined in my original post. Is this what you get, or did I make a mistake?

Comment: @agaminon I recommend working out the units as well. If that's 9.6 km, it may not be bad. Just use consistent units. I think orders of magnitude difference may rise from the difference of units.

Comment: @Newbie Yes it's 9644 meters or 9.6 km. I'm pretty sure all the units I used are consistent, maybe it's just that the estimation itself is no good.

Comment: You're considering up to 100 km altitude. Up to that altitude its mostly N$_{2}$ and O$_{2}$ so the variation of species shouldn't be an issue. Have you used lower temperatures? 288 K seems a bit high in my opinion. Lets assume that the temperature is constant for now.

Comment: @Newbie Perhaps 288 K is only correct for the lower atmosphere. I'll use lower values and see what I get.

Comment: Seems like for lower temperatures, one gets lower mass values, so it's not the temperature.

Comment: @agaminon Why do you stop at 100 km? Because that's what you call the edge of the atmosphere? You have an exponentially reducing function so you can integrate it far beyond 100 km if you know the profile of density is still acceptable. I know for a fact that the gas mixture changes considerably however.

Comment: @Newbie I ran the numbers for higher upper limits (1000 km, 10000 km, etc) and the value does not change much at all, seems like 10^5 is rather close to the asymptotic value.

Comment: @agaminon That makes sense because above 100 km altitude, you're already multiple Earth scale heights above the ground. Can you vary the temperature so you get the scale height down to 7.1 km from 9.6? Tell me how close the value gets.

Comment: @Newbie So varying the temperature so that the scale height is 7.1 km means the temperature should be 212.38 K; that gives you a result of 1.12 x 10^13 kg.

Comment: @agaminon I think if you've tried everything reasonable, probably that's not a good approximation you are using.

Comment: @Newbie Yeah, I quickly did another one calculating the mass of air in a 1 m^2 column of air that is 100 km tall, to then multiply that kg/m^2 value for Earth's surface and got an answer within correct bounds. So I guess the method I attempted at first contained too many assumptions and was too idealized to give a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I admire your mathematical skills in tackling the problem as you did. My innate lack thereof is the reason I gave up on physics as a topic of study in 1972. But here is an easy way to estimate the mass of the atmosphere, as a check:

Every square INCH (corrected!!!) of the earth's surface has 14.7 pounds' worth of air sitting on top of it. Take the surface area of the earth and multiply it by 14.7 and there's the answer in pounds.

Comment: Checked it and yes, it works perfectly fine! I guess I could calculate the mass of air per square meter myself to make it a bit more involved when presenting the problem. Nice idea.

Comment: @agaminon This should be the correct way of calculating the mass of the atmosphere. Unless your original approach, it does not require assumptions about the temperature dependence with height, and neither about the exact shape of earth.

Comment: @Thomas I assume then that I didn't make any mistakes in the derivation, rather the assumptions in the estimation are simply too approximate?

Comment: @DavidWhite absolutely right, my mistake, will correct right now!!! -NN

Comment: It is easier to remenber  $1kg/cm^2$

Comment: @DavidWhite. I posted that comment in gratitude for your correction. I am sorry if I did not make that sufficiently clear to you. -NN

Answer (score 0):

[The barometric formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula) is not applicable for this case for at least two reasons:

- It is a formula for flat Earth, i.e., it is valid only close to the surface - the $mgz$ in the numerator is actually the gravitational potential energy. As a minimum one needs to replace it by that for the spherical earth: $\phi(r)=-G\frac{Mm}{r}$, where $r$ is the distance to the Earth center (rather than the height above the surface).
- The [atmospheric density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_air) and pressure actually do not follow the barometric formula.

Comment: You can completely ignore the mass of the atmosphere above H=100 km, so the sphericity of the earth does not make any difference here as H<<R. Also, if you take the local temperature T and density $\rho$ then the obtained column density (and thus mass) will be automatically correct as it corresponds to the local pressure (see my own answer)

Comment: @Thomas One can do many different calculations and use many different models. The OP is trying to use the barometric formula, and I am addressing their approach.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your equation is to have $r$ in the exponential rather than $r-R$ (the exponential must be $1$ at the earth's surface ($r=R$)). With the latter you obtain from your integration (assuming $H$ and the atmospheric scale height $kT/(mg)$ both small compared to $R$)

$$M = 4\pi\cdot \rho(R) \frac{kT}{mg}\cdot R^2 \cdot(1-e^{-H\frac{mg}{kT}})$$

The second term in the bracket can be neglected if the the height $H$ is large compared to the atmospheric scale height. In this case the local vertical column density is simply the volume density at the earth's surface (or in general the chosen reference point) times the atmospheric scale height. Multiplied by the earth's surface area, you then have the mass of the atmosphere.